# Splitting a list/array into balanced sublists using python, where each pair in a sublist has a minimum specified difference

Tags: python, arrays, list, np

I'm trying to take a list or array of floats in python and separate them into the minimum (ish) number of chunks required for where the smallest pairwise spacing between each element in each chunk is above some threshold.

I've seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64079064/8188120), but I think this question is subtly different in that I would like to balance the size of each chunk by the end of the process, and the distances of each element need to be compared pairwise to all other elements not just adjacent ones.

Here is an example workflow that I've tried (and become stuck on):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# An example list of floats
lst = [1,2,3,3.3,3.5,3.9,4,5,6,8,10,12,13,15,18]
lst.sort()
lst=np.array(lst)
```

Next I would grab all of the elements whose pairwise distances to all other elements is acceptable based on some distance `threshold`. To do this I will generate a difference matrix, and select the rows (or columns) where the sum of pairwise distances isn't `nan`.

```
threshold = 1
diff = np.subtract.outer(lst, lst)
matrix = np.abs(diff)
#We don't care about the diagonal so set to any value that's not nan
matrix[matrix==0] = threshold 
#Highlight the pairs with distances below the threshold
matrix[matrix<threshold] = np.nan
```

Here is the distance matrix I'm using here:

```
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(matrix)
```

[image]

At this point I have an idealised chunk and a set of leftovers.

```
ideal_indices = matrix.sum(axis=1)>0
ideal_chunk = lst[ideal_indices]
remainders = lst[~ideal_indices]

print('Idealised chunk: ', ideal_chunk)
print('Remainders ', remainders)
```

Out:

```
Idealised chunk:  [ 1.  2.  5.  6.  8. 10. 12. 13. 15. 18.]
Remainders  [3.  3.3 3.5 3.9 4. ]
```

I would then think of finding a way to compare each remainder to the idealised chunk, and further split the idealised chunk up to incorporate (but keep separate) the remainders.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this whole process because it feels like I may have gone overboard for a first degree simple approach, baring in mind that this is almost certainly an NP-hard issue.

Any pointers or links would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One idea, your list is already sorted, when you calculate the difference with  `np.diff`, which is the distance between a pair of closed points, can we say if this distance is already greater than the threshold, that means other distances are much greater than the threshold. If the distance is smaller than threshold, you can just delete the left and right point?